# Obter timestamp

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp

Tenho duas variáveis, uma com a data e outra com a hora. Como posso obter o seu *timestamp* das duas variáveis. Exemplo:

```
var data = 02/01/2015;
var hora = 10:00:00;
var d = new Date(data + hora);
d.getTime();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É só uma questão de formatação do conteúdo. Primeiro você não pode ter a data e a hora assim solta, provavelmente você tem como *string*. E depois você precisa separar os dois conteúdos com um espaço em branco.

```js
var data = "02/01/2015";
var hora = "10:00:00";
var d = new Date(data + " " + hora);
console.log(d.getTime());
```

Veja [funcionando no **JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hyupyg8t/1/). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Typing/GetTimestamp.js).

Answer (score 5):

Você só precisa adicionar um espaço em braco pra separar a data da hora.

```
var data = "02/01/2015 ";
var hora = "10:00:00";
var d = new Date(data + hora);
d.getTime();
```

O método `getTime` retorna os timestamp em milisegundos.

Recomendo a leitura: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 2):

Tem dois pequenos detalhes que as outras respostas não se atentaram (e que pode fazer toda a diferença).

## Primeiro problema: formato da data

Quando você tem uma string que representa a data no formato "xx/yy/zzzz", alguns *browsers*/*runtimes* podem interpretar como "mês/dia/ano".

Por exemplo, o código abaixo (testei no Chrome e no Node, pode ser que em outros browsers/ambientes não ocorra o problema) cria uma data referente a 1 de fevereiro (quando o correto deveria ser 2 de janeiro):

```js
// 2 de janeiro
var data = "02/01/2015";

var hora = "10:00:00";
var d = new Date(data + " " + hora);

// Date refere-se a 1 de fevereiro em vez de 2 de janeiro
console.log(d.toString());
```

O que quer dizer que se você obter o timestamp desta data, não necessariamente será o valor que espera (pois o timestamp referente a 2 de janeiro é diferente do timestamp referente a 1 de fevereiro).

Pior ainda, se o dia for maior que 12, a data criada é inválida:

```js
// 22 de janeiro
var data = "22/01/2015";
var hora = "10:00:00";
var d = new Date(data + " " + hora);

// data inválida
console.log(d);
// NaN
console.log(d.getTime());
```

Pois como ela está sendo interpretada como "mês/dia/ano", ele tenta criar a data referente ao mês 22 (e como não existe, o resultado é uma data inválida).

Isso acontece porque o [único formato garantido pela especificação da linguagem](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) que funciona em qualquer ambiente é o definido pela [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (no caso, seria "aaaa-mm-dd"). Qualquer outro formato é dependente da implementação e **pode ou não funcionar**. Inclusive, [este comportamento é descrito na especificação da linguagem](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date.parse):

> *If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.*

Ou seja, qualquer outro formato que não seja o ISO 8601 pode ou não funcionar (como é o caso acima).

Sendo assim, uma opção seria converter a string para o formato ISO 8601:

```js
var data = "02/01/2015";
var [dia, mes, ano] = data.split('/');
data = `${ano}-${mes}-${dia}`;
var hora = "10:00:00";
var d = new Date(`${data}T${hora}`);

// 2 de janeiro (e não mais 1 de fevereiro)
console.log(d.toString());
console.log(d.getTime());
```

E repare que entre a data e a hora foi colocado um "T", conforme definido pela norma ISO 8601. É comum ver muitos códigos por aí que colocam um espaço, o que não é compatível com o ISO 8601, e como já dito acima, isso pode ou não funcionar (tenho notado que o espaço *geralmente* funciona, mas se quer ter certeza, prefira usar o formato indicado pela especificação).

Outra opção é extrair os valores numéricos e passá-los diretamente para o construtor:

```js
var data = "02/01/2015";
var hora = "10:00:00";
var [dia, mes, ano] = data.split('/').map(v => parseInt(v));
var [hora, minuto, segundo] = hora.split(':').map(v => parseInt(v));
var d = new Date(ano, mes - 1, dia, hora, minuto, segundo);

// 2 de janeiro (e não mais 1 de fevereiro)
console.log(d.toString());
console.log(d.getTime());
```

Só que neste caso temos que lembrar do **irritante** detalhe de que no JavaScript [os meses são indexados em zero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405998/112052) (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc) e por isso temos que subtrair 1 do mês (é confuso porque quando é uma string no formato ISO 8601, não precisa fazer isso, mas se for passar o valor numérico para o construtor, aí precisa).

Mas ainda não terminou. Eu disse que tinham dois pequenos detalhes, então vamos ao segundo.

## Segundo problema: timezones

O `Date` do JavaScript não é de fato uma data, pelo menos não no sentido de representar um único valor de dia, mês, ano, hora, minuto e segundo. Na verdade ele representa um [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) (um ponto na linha do tempo). Para ser mais preciso, o `Date` contém apenas um valor: a quantidade de milissegundos que se passaram desde o Unix Epoch (que é o "instante zero", e corresponde a 1 de janeiro de 1970, à meia-noite, em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)).

O problema é que se tivermos apenas a data e a hora, isso não é suficiente para termos o timestamp, pois precisamos saber a qual timezone (fuso horário) ele se refere. O código acima só "funciona" porque o JavaScript usa um timezone implicitamente (o que está configurado no ambiente no qual ele roda, seja o browser, o Node, etc).

Só que o mesmo código acima, rodando em ambientes diferentes, dará resultados diferentes. Por exemplo, qual o timestamp referente ao dia 2 de janeiro de 2015, às 10 da manhã? Depende, pois em cada parte do mundo esta data e hora ocorreu em instantes diferentes. No Japão, ela ocorreu 11 horas antes, se comparado à São Paulo (não é 12 horas porque aqui estávamos em horário de verão). Mas em vários estados do Nordeste não teve horário de verão, então lá mesma data e hora só ocorreu 1 hora depois de São Paulo. E em cada parte do mundo esta data e hora ocorreu em um instante diferente. Por isso, dependendo do timezone utilizado, o valor do timestamp poderá ser diferente.

Claro que se você quer usar o timezone que está configurado no browser, basta usar o código acima. Mas lembre-se que os resultados poderão ser diferentes, pois depende do timezone que está configurado no ambiente no qual o código roda e você não tem controle sobre isso.

Porém, se quiser usar algum timezone específico, o JavaScript não possui uma forma fácil de fazer ([ainda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/495075/112052)), e o jeito é recorrer a bibliotecas externas (exemplos: [1](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/zones?id=creating-datetimes-in-a-zone), [2](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/Time-Zones#synopsis), [3](https://day.js.org/docs/en/timezone/converting-to-zone)).

---

Para mais detalhes sobre o `Date` do JavaScript, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/456089/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455437/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408160/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/416172/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/469717/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344030/112052).

Answer (score 1):

**1º Forma**

```
function TimeStamp(){
   return new Date().getTime();
} alert(TimeStamp());
```

**2º Forma**

```
function TimeStamp() {
    var d = new Date();
    var timestamp = d.getTime();
    return timestamp;
} alert(TimeStamp());
```

**3º Forma**

```
function TimeStamp() {
    return event.timeStamp;
} alert(TimeStamp());
```

**Importante!** Se usar o getTime() para obter o timestamp real devera fazer a conversão abaixo.

```
Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
```

O `getTime()` retorna milissegundos desde a época `UNIX`, então dividi-lo por 1000 para obter a representação de segundos. Ele é arredondado usando `Math.round()` para torná-lo um número inteiro. O resultado agora tem o `timestamp UNIX` a data atual e relevando tempo para o navegador do usuário.