# Criar Date passando números tem resultado diferente de passar uma string com os mesmos valores

Tags: javascript, data

Estou estudando a parte de datas do JavaScript e vi algo que não sei explicar.

Segue o código:

```js
var envio = new Date(2018, 02, 20);
var envio2 = new Date("2018-02-20");

console.log("Virgula: " + envio);
console.log("String: " + envio2);
```

O resultado que isso me traz:

```
Virgula: Tue Mar 20 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília) scripts.js:489:13
String: Mon Feb 19 2018 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
```

Entendi que no caso do mês, a versão com vírgula, conta a partir do zero, mas não entendi o motivo de na versão com string, estar com o dia 19.

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 4):

Quando você chama o construtor passando números, [o mês é indexado em zero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405998/112052) (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc). Então `new Date(2018, 02, 20)` corresponde a 20 de março. Se quer 20 de fevereiro, faça `new Date(2018, 1, 20)`.

Outro detalhe é que ele seta o horário para meia-noite no fuso horário do ambiente no qual está rodando (no caso do *browser*, geralmente ele usa o do sistema operacional). Por isso no seu teste o resultado foi 20 de março à meia-noite no Horário de Brasília ([este trecho da documentação](http://Individual_date_and_time_component_values) diz que os campos não informados - no caso, a hora, minuto e segundo - são setados para zero, por isso o horário é meia-noite).

Já quando você passa uma string no [formato ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) contendo somente a data (sem o horário), o mês é indexado em 1 (janeiro é 1, fevereiro é 2, etc) e o horário é setado para meia-noite em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (que por sua vez, corresponde à 9 da noite do dia anterior no Horário de Brasília, já que o Horário de Brasília está 3 horas atrás do UTC - ou 2 horas, quando é horário de verão). Mas quando você imprime a data, ela é mostrada no fuso horário do browser, por isso ela mostra dia 19 de fevereiro às 21h (pois dia 19 às 21h no Horário de Brasília equivale a dia 20 à meia-noite em UTC).

Para ser mais preciso, a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Timestamp_string) cita que ao passar uma string para o construtor de `Date`, ele usa a mesma lógica do método [`parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). E este, por sua vez, usa [estas regras](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Date_Time_String_Format) (e neste link está descrito o que eu já disse acima: "*date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time and date-time forms are interpreted as local time*").

---

Ou seja, se você colocar o horário na string, aí ele considera o fuso horário do browser:

```js
// sem horário, considera meia-noite em UTC
console.log('UTC: ' + new Date("2018-02-20"));

// com horário, considera o fuso horário do browser
console.log('Fuso do browser: ' + new Date("2018-02-20T00:00"));
```

Isso tudo acontece porque o `Date` do JavaScript na verdade representa um [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) (um ponto na linha do tempo), não uma data específica (um único valor de dia, mês, ano, hora, minuto e segundo).

Para mais detalhes, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/456089/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455437/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408160/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/416172/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344030/112052).