# Problema na conversão de string para date.parse JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, data, conversão, nan

Estou recebendo em uma variável valor de data em `string` e fazendo a conversão para data, para conseguir fazer uma condição. O problema é que quando a data vem como `31/12`, a variável fica `NaN`.
Segue abaixo o exemplo:

```
function ValidaDataVersao(escopoGrade)
{
    debugger;   
    dataInicial = Date.parse(escopoGrade.registroSelecionado.DataInicial);
    dataFinal = Date.parse(escopoGrade.registroSelecionado.DataFinal);
    let sequenciaValida = true;

    if (dataInicial > dataFinal) {
                smartBox.Alerta(null,
                    'Cancelado!',
                    "Data Inicial deve ser menor que Data Final.",
                    6000);

                sequenciaValida = false;
                return false;
        }
    return sequenciaValida;
}
let escopoGrade = angular.element('#gradePerfilECDVersoes').scope();

if (escopoGrade)
{
    escopoGrade.adicionarCriticas(function () { 
        return ValidaDataVersao(escopoGrade); 
    });
}
```

Se a data que vier na `string` for `31/12/2020`, por exemplo a variável fica como `NaN` e ai não consigo fazer a comparação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Segundo a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), o único formato que é garantido que funcione da mesma forma em todos os *browsers* (descrito [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Date_Time_String_Format)) é baseado na norma [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (no seu exemplo, seria "2020-12-31"). **Qualquer outro formato não é garantido**, pois a mesma documentação cita:

> *If the String does not conform to the standard format the function may fall back to any implementation–specific heuristics or implementation–specific parsing algorithm. Unrecognizable strings or dates containing illegal element values in ISO formatted strings shall cause Date.parse() to return NaN.*

Ou seja, qualquer outro formato que não seja o ISO 8601 pode ou não funcionar dependendo da implementação (versão do browser ou da *engine* - [Node](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js), [Deno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deno), etc), mesmo que a string seja uma data válida em alguns contextos - "31/12/2020" pode ou não ser válido, pois no formato americano, por exemplo (mês/dia/ano) ela é inválida, apesar de ser válida em outros países.

O fato é que, por não estar no formato ISO 8601, não é garantido que funcione (por exemplo, no Chrome, "12/31/2020" funciona, mas "31/12/2020" não, o que indica que ele interpreta essa data como estando no formato americano).

Enfim, nesse caso não tem muito jeito a não ser quebrar a string em partes e construir a data manualmente:

```js
let s = "31/12/2020";
let [dia, mes, ano] = s.split("/");
let data = new Date(ano, mes - 1, dia);
console.log(data);
```

Lembrando que tive que subtrair 1 do mês, pois no `Date` [os meses são indexados em zero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405998/112052) (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc).

---

Outra opção, caso possa adicionar uma *lib* externa, é usar o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/):

```js
// converte a string para data, o formato DD/MM/YYYY indica como fazer o parsing corretamente
let m = moment("31/12/2020", "DD/MM/YYYY");
// converter para Date
let data = m.toDate();
console.log(data);

// para comparar com outra data, não precisaria converter para Date
let m2 = moment("28/12/2020", "DD/MM/YYYY");
if (m.isAfter(m2)) console.log('m é depois de m2');
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

Para saber mais sobre o assunto, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408160/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/416172/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/469717/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/456089/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455437/112052), e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344030/112052).

Comment: Parabéns mano! Esse foi o único jeito que funcionou mesmo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver pesquisando. A solução foi quebrar pelo Split transformando em Array e depois dar um new Date. Ficou assim:

```
        function ValidaDataVersao(escopoGrade)
        {
            let dataInicialArray = escopoGrade.registroSelecionado.DataInicial.split("/");
            let dataInicial = new Date(dataInicialArray[2], dataInicialArray[1]-1, dataInicialArray[0]);

            let dataFinalArray = escopoGrade.registroSelecionado.DataFinal.split("/");
            let dataFinal = new Date(dataFinalArray[2], dataFinalArray[1]-1, dataFinalArray[0]);

            let sequenciaValida = true;

            if (dataInicial > dataFinal) {
                        smartBox.Alerta(null,
                            'Cancelado!',
                            "Data Inicial deve ser menor que Data Final.",
                            6000);

                        sequenciaValida = false;
                        return false;
                }
            return sequenciaValida;
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode fazer um `Date.parse` de uma data inválida. A [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) da Mozilla diz isso:

> O método Date.parse() analisa uma representação de data em string, e
> retorna o número de milisegundos desde 01 de Janeiro de 1970, 00:00:00
> UTC ou NaN se a string não for reconhecida ou, em alguns casos,
> contiver valores inválidos de data (ex. 2015-02-31).

Como ajuda, deixo um script que utilizo para criação e formatação de datas:

```
const options = { year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric" };
const date = new Date(2020, 11, 31) // 2020-12-31T03:00:00.000Z
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("pt-br", options))
// 31 de dezembro de 2020
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("pt-br", { ...options, month: 'numeric'}))
// 31/12/2020
```