# Como pegar de volta uma data formatada no formato MMM/yyyy para o formato yyyy-MM com date-fns

Tags: javascript, data, formatação, date-fns

Eu quero pegar o valor de uma date string formatada como `MMM/yyyy` para  o formato `yyyy-MM`.

Por exemplo, para `abr/2017`, quero retornar `2017-04`.

Eu escrevi o seguinte código com a biblioteca `date-fns`, porém não está funcionando:

```
import format from 'date-fns/format';
import ptBR from 'date-fns/locale/pt-BR';

format(new Date('abr/2017'),'yyyy-MM', { locale: ptBR })
```

Comment: O primeiro argumento de format() não tem de ser uma data, em vez de string? Talvez com a função toDate()?

Comment: Eu corrigi lá... Esse é o código que eu estou tentando rodar, @epx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, `new Date('abr/2017')` não funciona da maneira que você espera:

```js
// cada browser dá um resultado (Chrome: 01/01/2017 - Firefox: null/invalid date)
console.log(new Date('abr/2017'));
```

Testando no Node e no Chrome, o resultado foi uma data em 1 de janeiro de 2017, mas no Firefox deu "invalid date".

Isso porque o construtor de `Date` não aceita qualquer string em qualquer formato. Apenas [os formatos indicados na especifição](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) são garantidos que funcionem em todos os browsers/ambientes. Qualquer outro formato é dependente da implementação e não há garantia nenhuma que funcione (*sobre isso e muito mais, leia mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/456089/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455437/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408160/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/416172/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/469717/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344030/112052)*).

---

Enfim, se você tem a string "abr/2017" e quer convertê-la para outro formato, então primeiro você precisa converter esta string para uma data (ou seja, fazer um *parsing*) e depois converter esta data para o outro formato (ou seja, fazer uma *formatação*). Ou seja, você também vai precisar da [função `parse`](https://date-fns.org/v2.21.3/docs/parse):

```js
import format from 'date-fns/format';
import ptBR from 'date-fns/locale/pt-BR';
import parse from 'date-fns/parse';

// converter "abr/2017" para data
var data = parse('abr/2017', 'MMM/yyyy', new Date(), { locale: ptBR });
// converte a data para o outro formato
console.log(format(data, 'yyyy-MM', { locale: ptBR })); // 2017-04
```

Repare que no `parse` eu preciso informar o formato em que a string está (no caso, `MMM/yyyy`), para que ele interprete corretamente. No terceiro argumento passei `new Date()`, que ele usa como referência para preencher os campos restantes (pois a string só tem mês e ano, então ele precisa saber o que colocar nos outros campos - neste caso não faz tanta diferença porque só estou usando a data para formatar os mesmos campos). E por fim, informo o *locale* para que ele saiba interpretar corretamente o nome do mês.

Já na formatação, como só estou colocando os valores numéricos, nem precisava do *locale* (poderia ser apenas `format(data, 'yyyy-MM')` que já seria o suficiente).